# What are the Stotras to worship Indra, Agni, Vayu, Soma, and Yama?

Tags: worship, stotra, puja, vedic-gods

What are the Mantras in Epics, Puranas and Agamas and also, other Stotras to worship Indra, Agni, Vayu, Soma, and Yama?